# Authentication with web2py on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web2py

Having never used [web2py](http://www.web2py.com) before, I am considering using it in a new App Engine application. But I am not able to ascertain whether its [access control](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09/access-control) mechanisms will work as is on app engine.

Can I use the web2py user framework totally independent of the app engine infrastructure? Meaning that I can add local users and roles and use them that do not depend on Google or OpenID authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the web2py Auth system on App Engine. The only limitation is that if you are using the Google Datastore, `auth.accessible_query()` won't work because it requires a join.